# Medieval physician Cornelius Shilander?

Tags: middle-ages, medicine

I am doing a research related to history of military medicine. I came up with a book published 1596 by Cornelius Shilander.

https://archive.org/details/corneliusshiland00schi

I have tried to do some background research on this author. I have found absolutely nothing. The first couple of thousand Google pages include only searches which state this said book. How could this be possible? Each and every other Medieval surgeon and physician I have come across have been mentioned countless of times across different websites and other books.

Comment: @TylerDurden which is an alias for Ben Stiller....? I don´t get this

Comment: @arkiaamu I'm sorry, he's just a troll. No clue what triggered him this time, he just does not make much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variant spelling of his last name is Schylander. [Here](http://www.dbnl.org/tekst/molh003nieu07_01/molh003nieu07_01_1883.php)'s a capsule biography of him (in Dutch), which might be a useful starting point.

Comment: Great! Thank, I wonder why google did not offer this one, since the misspelling is only one letter...

Comment: @arkiaamu Two, actually (an extra C, and a Y instead of an I).